# Express , Mongoose , Actulalizar o añadir un array dentro de otro array

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, backend

Hoy me prensento con el siguiente incoveniente con siguiente modelo

```
const UniversitySchema = Schema({

university_name: { type: String, require: [true, 'El nombre es Obligatorio'] },
university_id: { type: String, require: [true, 'El ID es Obligatorio'] },
university_password: { type: String, require: [true, 'El ID es Obligatorio'] },
university_direction: {
    sede: String,
    city: String,
    addres: String,
    department: String,
},
university_faculty: [{
    name: String,
    programs: [{
        name: String,
    }]
}],
university_img: String,
university_create_at: String,
university_update_at: String,
```

});

lo que deseo es crear un metodo en el cual se le suminisstra 3 valores el id de la universidad , el nombre de la faculta y el nombre del programa academico en la cual con id de la universidad y el nombre de la faculta poder filtar el campo que busco y asi añadir el programa ala universidad y facultad correspodiente.

Quiero guardar un objeto en university_faculty[i].programs.

ya lo intentado varias formas y no lo e logrado, seria de mucha ayuda que em aconsejaran como hacerlo , esta es una de ellas pero no funciona

```
University.findOne({ university_id: params.university_id }, (err, universityDB) => {

    if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al buscar la universidad en la BD', err });

    if (!universityDB) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'La universidad no existe', universityDB });

    for (let i = 0; i < universityDB.university_faculty.length; i++) {

        if (universityDB.university_faculty[i].name == params.university_faculty_name) {

            universityDB.university_faculty[i].programs = params.university_programs_name;
            universityDB.save();


            return res.status(200).send({
                message: universityDB.university_faculty[i].programs
            });
        }


    }



    return res.status(200).send({
        universityDB,
    });
})
```

Comment: Hola. No se entiende muy bien cual es tu problema. Quieres hacer una busqueda? Puedes editar la pregunta con estas aclaraciones para formular una respuesta. Bienvenido!

Comment: Listo ya modifique la pregunta, espero esta ves lo entiendas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varías formas de resolver este problema. El más simple es que en tu frontend obtengas los id´s que genera mongoose automáticamente dentro de cada array, en tu caso `university_id` y uno nuevo,  `id_university_faculty`.

```javascript
    University.findOne({
      university_id: params.university_id
    }, async(err, c) => {

      if (err) return res.status(500).send({
        message: 'Error al buscar la universidad en la BD',
        err
      });

      if (!universityDB) return res.status(404).send({
        message: 'La universidad no existe',
        universityDB
      });


      universityDB.university_faculty
        //Este es el secreto. Dentro de mongoose todos los arreglos
        //tienen la funcion id()
        .id(id_university_faculty)
        .programs
        //Programs es un array de objetos. Necesita un objeto.
        .push({name:"Nuevo programa"})


      //Ahora, aqui tienes que guardar de nuevo. Uso async-await para
      // no crear mas lógica, pero lo correcto es que hagas el try-catch
      // o que utilices promesas. 

      universityDB = await universityDB.save()


      return res.status(200).send({
        universityDB,
      });
    })
```

Comment: Esta muy bien tu repuesta pero al momento de saver el save en universityDB  sale el siguiente error , por que creo me esta pidiendo el _id del objeto de programs |||     UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: University validation failed: university_faculty.0.programs.0._id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "perradas" at path "_id"

Comment: @AlexisRojas Correji mi respuesta. El push necesita un objeto puesto que el array no es un string plano.

Comment: Muchas gracias fuiste de gran ayuda y ahora entiendo mucho mejor el mongose , te deseo suerte y muchos exitos